# Python SSL with PKCS#12 certificates

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

Is there some way to wrap a socket connection with SSL using python's ssl module in python 2.6 using a pkcs#12 file?  The file contains a private key and certificate.  I want to use them for the client side of the connection. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630011/error-using-httlibs-httpsconnection-with-pkcs12-certificate) seems to hint that it may be possible but doesn't give a real definitive answer.

Comment: The client only needs a private key and certificate when the server requires SSL client authentication, which is rare.

Comment: Rare but exactly what I need to do.

Comment: This gist could be useful: https://gist.github.com/erikbern/756b1d8df2d1487497d29b90e81f8068

Answer (score 2):

Not with python's ssl module. M2Crypto can't do this also at the moment, nor does python-gnutls. If you've got openssl command available on your client machine, you can re-export that pkcs12 to pem format running the openssl command, and use the results, something like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in your_pkcs.p12 -out client_certs.pem -clcerts -nokeys [password options]
openssl pkcs12 -in your_pkcs.p12 -out keys.pem -nocerts [password options]
```

However PKCS12 is [utterly broken by design](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/pfx.html), while still popular, you should avoid it if possible.