# python: APNs SSLError

Tags: python, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notifications to iPhone via python as described [here](http://leenux.org.uk/2009/07/14/push-on-the-iphone/) but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/omat/CA/server/ca/models.py", line 193, in push
    c.connect((host_name, 2195))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 307, in connect
    self.ca_certs)
SSLError: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:337: error:140B0009:SSL routines:
  SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

The error is raised from within the python ssl module as the traceback says but the message doesn't sing to me. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Thanks,

oMat

**edit:**

The certificate used is created from the certificate and the private key as follows:

```
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out apns-dev-cert.pem -in apns-dev-cert.p12
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out apns-dev-key.pem -in apns-dev-key.p12
cat apns-dev-cert.pem apns-dev-key.pem > apns-dev.pem
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error using httlib's HTTPSConnection with PKCS#12 certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630011/error-using-httlibs-httpsconnection-with-pkcs12-certificate)

Comment: both certificates in this case are PEM certificates

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is how I get it working:

From within KeyChain export the following both in `p12` format, without giving password:

- `Apple Development Push Services` certificate as `cert.p12`
- `primary key` under `Apple Development Push Services` as `pkey.p12`

In terminal go to the directory where you have exported the certificates and convert the `p12` files to `pem` format and concatenate them as follows:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in pkey.p12 -out pkey.pem -nodes -clcerts
$ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
$ cat cert.pem pkey.pem > iphone_ck.pem
```

`iphone_ck.pem` is the certificate you need.

Comment: i am having similar issues, but I cannot find the primary key under Apple Development Push Services, how exactly did you find it? Thanks for the great response btw. @omat

Comment: Check the Keys directory in Keychains. Its a private key under the name you created with your CSR cert.

Comment: Actually, the way to figure out the private key is to look in Xcode and see what the Code Signing Authority is - the Private Key will match this. Also, when you run the openSSL command you will be prompted for a password - assuming you did not specify one on the export just hit return. Whew! This finally got my push to work!

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same error message using [PyAPNs](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs).  The example says to initiate it like this:

```
apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='cert.pem', key_file='key.pem')
```

Turns out the solution to my problem was to include the full system path for each .pem file:

```
cert_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cert.pem')
key_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'key.pem')
apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file=cert_path, key_file=key_path)
```

Comment: It's really strange, but it's the solution even when the `cert.pem` and `key.pem` stays at the same level hierarchy, nice answer!!